# can django admin leverage rest framework filters?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I have setup my models to use:

```
import rest_framework_filters as filters

class FoundationIPFilter(filters.FilterSet):
  foundation_ip_team_group = 
  filters.RelatedFilter(FoundationIPTeamGroupFilter, name='foundation_ip_team_group', queryset=FoundationIPTeamGroup.objects.all(), lookups='__all__')
technology = filters.RelatedFilter(TechnologyFilter, name='technology', queryset=Technology.objects.all(), lookups='__all__')

class Meta:
    model = FoundationIP
    fields = '__all__'
```

when i use the rest api to do complex foreign key filtering on FoundationIP, everything works fine.  ie, this works:

```
<myurl>/tracker/foundationip/?technology__name=sec11lpp
```

when i use the same filtering in the admin interface, i get all results returned or i get error "filtering by  not allowed"

```
<myurl>/admin/tracker/foundationip/?technology__name=sec11lpp
```

i think it's because the admin somehow isn't using the same filters as rest_framework, ie not loading the filters i have in filters.py.  how can i get the admin to do this, ie use the same filters?

my admin models look like:

```
class FoundationIPAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 list_display = ["id", "name", "technology", "foundation_ip_team_group", "design_type"]
 list_display_links = ["id"]
 list_filter = ["name", "technology", "foundation_ip_team_group"]
 list_editable = ["name", "design_type", "foundation_ip_team_group"]
 list_max_show_all = 200
 class Meta:
    model = FoundationIP
```

Comment: any ideas here folks? did i ask a dumb/obvious question?